# Vertical Scroll Automation on Button Click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Need help with automating vertical scrolling.  I'm a teacher and my 15 year old son is learning C# to help with making online worksheets.  We are currently making a computer based worksheet that teaches 3 phonics sounds using 3 letter words (cat, dog, fox, etc).  The form is constructed of four rows with 5 pictures in each row. The actual worksheet used as a template can be seen at http://www.tampareads.com/phonics/phondesk/cvc/cvc-1.htm - Because of size limitations I am displaying only 2 rows at a time.  When the student clicks on the correct letter for the last problem in row 2 we want the form to scroll down to view rows 3 and 4.  Is there a way to get have the form to scroll down to view these last 2 rows automatically, so the student does not have to scroll manually? We've been reading and trying for days but no luck.  We tried using "ScrollControlIntoView" but it would appear to work, but then when clicking the answer of the first problem in row 3, it jumps back up to row 1.  We are pulling our hair out!! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IF your using jQuery or could add it to your page, you could do something like this.

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop() + 100

$('.correctLetter').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ position }, 'slow');
});
```

Position = the amount already scrolled down the page + 100.  You may need to adjust the 100 to however many pixels you need to scroll.

$(.correctLetter) refers to a class on whatever element you want to trigger the scroll.

Comment: Hello - thanks for the input.  Do you know if JQuery can be added to Microsoft Visual Studio using C# and if so how it would be done?

Comment: if you have access to the <head></head> section of your site, you would just add...

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>